# Is the use of , (comma) instead of a proper variable definition like const, var or let, in a chain of declarations, a good JS practice?

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript-6

i've recently discovered that i can use `,` (comma) instead of declaring the variable properly like `const num1`, when in a chain mode, what i want to know is if there is any side effects in using it?

the std way =>

```
const num1 = 1
const num2 = 2
const num3 = 3
```

The , way =>

```
const num1 = 1
, num2 = 2
, num3 = 3
```

! the console shows no syntax error on both of them !

Comment: There's no difference between them. All the declaration statements allow you to declare multiple variables, separating them with comma.

Comment: Note that the second example is equivalent to `const num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 3;`. It is just formatted on multiple lines. Usually when formatting like this, the comma is at the end of each line instead of the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is totally equivalent same.

You can refer **Declaring and initializing two variables**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 2):

There's actually no difference, as long as you know that the comma syntax keeps the kind of variable (block scoping, constant) the same all the way through. So this:

```
const num1 = 1;
const num2 = 2;
const num3 = 3;
```

Is exactly the same as this:

```
const num1 = 1,
  num2 = 2,
  num3 = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the second example is equivalent to

```
const num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 3;
```

This makes it clear that you are just declaring a list of variables separated with a comma. Traditionally, this is formatted as

```
const num1 = 1,
      num2 = 2,
      num3 = 3;
```

Note that here the comma is at the end of the line. You just happened to stumble on this a slightly different form of this same thing.